# Function stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c, file-io, infinite-loop, fgets

First post here. I've built a function thats supposed to get a string and an integer from two separate files, and store them into two variables. My code is:

```
void getCompanyData(char * companyData, int * checkNum){

char buffer[100];
FILE * tempFile1;
FILE * tempFile2;

tempFile1 = fopen("./companyData.txt", "r");
if (tempFile1 == NULL) {
    printf("The file failed to open!\n");
    exit(1);
}
while ((fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), tempFile1) != NULL)){
    strcat(companyData, buffer);
}
fclose(tempFile1);

tempFile2 = fopen("./checkNum.txt", "r");
if (tempFile2 == NULL){
    printf("The file failed to open!\n");
    exit(1);
}
while (tempFile2 != NULL){
    fscanf(tempFile2, "%d", checkNum);
}
fclose(tempFile2);
```

}

From companyData.txt:

```
Sabre Corporation
15790 West Henness Lane
New Corio, New Mexico 65790
```

From checkNum.txt:
    100

Comment: Also the function call was:     getCompanyData(companyData, &checkNum);

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @CoolGuy Sorry, edited the post. The function gets enters an infinite loop while retrieving data from companyData.txt, where I'm trying to concatenate the buffer into the companyData array. My question is, whats wrong with the function?

Comment: Read my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is stuck in an infinite loop because your last `while` loop will never end. The below loop is the one making problems:

```
while (tempFile2 != NULL){
    fscanf(tempFile2, "%d", checkNum);
}
```

Change that to

```
fscanf(tempFile2, "%d", checkNum);
```

and your code will work. You don't need to check `tempFile != NULL` because you already check it in the `if` before the loop.Also,it is a good practise to check if `fscanf` was successful. So use

```
if(fscanf(tempFile2, "%d", checkNum)==1)
    //successfully scanned an integer from tempFile2
else
    //failed to scan an integer from tempFile2
```